# Move edge along normal of other face?

Tags: modeling

I have the following situation:

[image]

I want to move the edge highlighted in the second image along the direction of the face of the first image. I'm fairly new to blender, so I'm asking if there's a simple way to do this (e.g. no scripts).

Answer (score 8):

You can use *Edge slide* (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>*>Edge slide*) to do this:

[image]

Note that <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> will call *edge slide* or *vertex slide* depending on the selected topology.
In your case, it will call *vertex slide*. To get the desired result with vertex slide, position the cursor so that all the vertices are sliding along the desired edges, then press <kbd>C</kbd> to clamp them to that edge:

[image]

Vertex slide is also accessible with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: oops, i overlooked the G G. cool !

Comment: @GaiaClary My answer was a bit unclear.. I was about to upvote your answer, as it's a perfectly valid solution.. I'll upvote it if you undelete it :)

Comment: ok, then i undelete it again :) I just think your answer is so much easier to use.

Comment: But there may be cases where it's not applicable, and another approach is required. This way more options are available to the OP (or anyone else) :)

Answer (score 8):

edge slide <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> does not work in this usage case, because of the topology. besides the solution provided by Gandalf3, here is a somewhat more complicated alternative which i just keep here as a sidenote:

1. Select the Face along which you want to move the edge:

   [image]
2. Set the 3D Manipulator widget's Transform orientatin to "View"
3. View -> Align View -> Align View to Active -> Top

   [image]
4. Select Edge Select Mode
5. Select the edges that you want to slide

now you can slide the edges upwards and be sure they slide along the face that you selected in 1. above